# Why does this mod_rewrite rule 'not-match'? (big rewrite log included)

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, .htaccess, rewrite, rewritecond

I've got a scenario involving two domains:

1. WordPress site hosted on domain1.com
2. domain2.co.uk, simply redirecting users to domain1 via mod_rewrite

This rule applies irrespective of whether www. is specified or not. (It's eventually removed from the URL, I'm a no-WWW fan.)

There's nothing on domain2.co.uk at all except for an .htaccess with some mod_rewrite rules. However, I want to be able to allow users to be redirected to the correct article URI even if they specify the "wrong" URL (i.e., a 301 redirect preserving the stuff after the first forward slash).

I'm currently achieving this with this ruleset:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?[^\.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works but is uglier than I want it to be. I'm not a mod_rewrite zen master, but from what I can tell the top rule *should* match irrespective of whether www. is specified... But it doesn't. In order to catch www-less requests, I need the second RewriteCond.

From the rewrite log, with just the first RewriteCond:

```
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e670168/initial] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/ -> 
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e670168/initial] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e670168/initial] (4) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='domain2.co.uk' pattern='^((www\.)|[^\.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk' [NC] => not-matched
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e670168/initial] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e653868/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.html
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65f8b8/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.htm
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e653868/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.shtml
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65f8b8/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.php
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e653868/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.php5
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e666c98/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.php4
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65f8b8/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.php3
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e653868/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.phtml
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65f8b8/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/index.cgi
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e66c370/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/403.shtml -> 403.shtml
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e66c370/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '403.shtml'
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e66c370/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='domain2.co.uk' pattern='^((www\.)|[^\.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk' [NC] => not-matched
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e66c370/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/403.shtml
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e668ca8/initial] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e668ca8/initial] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e668ca8/initial] (4) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='domain2.co.uk' pattern='^((www\.)|[^\.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk' [NC] => not-matched
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e668ca8/initial] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/favicon.ico
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#f160b40/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/404.shtml -> 404.shtml
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#f160b40/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '404.shtml'
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#f160b40/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='domain2.co.uk' pattern='^((www\.)|[^\.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk' [NC] => not-matched
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#f160b40/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] pass through /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/404.shtml
```

However with the second RewriteCond added, the rule works, and the logs show this:

```
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65fe58/initial] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/ -> 
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65fe58/initial] (3) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65fe58/initial] (4) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='domain2.co.uk' pattern='^((www\.)?[^\.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk' [NC] => not-matched
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65fe58/initial] (4) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='domain2.co.uk' pattern='^domain2\.co\.uk' [NC] => matched
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65fe58/initial] (2) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] rewrite '' -> 'http://domain1.com/'
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65fe58/initial] (2) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://domain1.com/
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65fe58/initial] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] escaping http://domain1.com/ for redirect
[domain2.co.uk/sid#e200498][rid#e65fe58/initial] (1) [perdir /home/devnull/domains/domain2.co.uk/public_html/] redirect to http://domain1.com/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

Can anybody help me figure out why it just won't work with the one rule? I feel like I'm missing the bleeding obvious, and while the second RewriteCond is a valid workaround, it's a kludge and that annoys me. ;-) All help appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine

> `^((www\.)?[^\.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk`

It matches if the Host header is `www.`*something*`.domain2.co.uk` or just *something*`.domain2.co.uk`.  However, it only matches when the Host header ends in `.domain2.co.uk`, so `domain2.co.uk` doesn't match.

Simpler answer: You want to redirect everything anyway, so just remove both `RewriteCond`s altogether.

Comment: "so just remove both RewriteConds altogether." - By the sound of it, a simple `Redirect` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your rule was looking for anything that started with www, optionally, followed by a . with any number of additional dots, followed by a required .

```
^((www\.)?[^\.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk
```

Comment: Ah, does "^\." after the ungreedy denote "." instead of any single character? I cribbed some existing code, learnt backwards as best I could to understand its functionality then made a couple of slight modifications.

Am I right in thinking that

^((www\.)?[^.]+)\.domain2\.co\.uk

would handle www.domain.tld or sub.domain.tld and just pass on any URI to domain1.tld/uri in a wildcard fashion? If not, what am I doing wrong? ;-)

(I'm also thinking that it'd be simpler to have subdomain requests parsed by entirely separate rule to preserve sanity, think that's the best way to proceed?)

Comment: I would just do   ^(.*)\.?domain2\.co\.uk in that case

Comment: The \ before the . is an escape character, meaning that it matches a . and not the regex for .